# Bind data frames row wise in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, do.call

I want to perform monte-carlo simulations with mean (i) varying from 5 to 60 by an interval of 5 and j varying from 0 to 1 by 0.125. As an output of the following code I want the data frame obtained for each  j to bind along the row. For instance, if I want to perform 10,000 simulations for a given j, the resultant data frame (i.e. DF1) will have 12 columns and 10000 rows, where 12 represents the length of i (i.e. 60/50. Subsequently, DF1 for each j should bind row wise. Thus, for 8 values of j the final data frame, DF2 will have 80000 rows and 12 columns. However, on running this code I receive this error message: "Error in datalist[[j]] <- DF1 :
attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex"

The code is:

```
datalist = list()
for (j in seq(0, 1, 0.125)){
  DF1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) setNames(data.frame(rlnorm(n=10000, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))), i)))
  datalist[[j]] <- DF1
}
DF2 = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Comment: So in the first iteration of your loop `j` is `0`. You're trying to base your loop on the sequence `seq(0, 1, 0.125)` rather than on an integer sequence, so you can't subset on `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much less complicated way to do this. First you probably don't really want `j=0` since that makes the standard deviation zero and all of the values are constant, but I'll keep to the parameters you set:

```
ivals <- seq(5, 60, 5)
jvals <- seq(0, 1, 0.125)
n <- 10                      # Just 10 values for testing
ijval <- expand.grid(ival=ivals, jval=jvals)  # 108 combinations of i and j
draw <- function(i, j, n) {rlnorm(n, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))}
DF <- t(mapply(draw, i=ijval$ival, j=ijval$jval, n=n))   # 108 rows by n columns
```

Note that you can `DF2 <- cbind(ijval, DF)` if you want the columns indicating the i and j values for each row.